# Why can't I add numeric(n,m) field values to PostGIS geometries in QGIS 1.7.1?

Tags: qgis, postgis

Actually I'm using QGIS 1.7.1 to create and visualise some geodata hosted by PostgreSQL 8.4 and PostGIS 1.4.0. The geodatatable is defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE u2_baum
(
    baum_id integer NOT NULL,
    kronendurchmesser numeric(3,1),
    hoehe numeric(3,1),
    art_id integer,
    the_geom geometry,
    CONSTRAINT baum_id PRIMARY KEY (baum_id )
)
WITH (
    OIDS=FALSE
);
```

I added some datasets on database level, using some simple INSERTs.

Everything works fine, except adding attributes to new geometries in QGIS.  I am able to define the geometry and all integer attributes using the QGIS tools. The only problems were caused by the attributes with the numerical[n,m] fieldtype. One can't enter new values in these fields after creating a new geometry. The field can be "write activated" in the attribute table, but it isn't possible to enter values. Also it isn't possible to Copy and Paste some values (like 10.3) into this fields. But it is possible to change existing numerical[n,m] values.

Do you know this error and a way to fix it?

PS: Due to some restrictions I can't actually upgrade to QGIS 1.8

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this issue is fixed in QGIS 1.8.0. I guess that I need to update my installations.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a reference to the fix.